# How does UUID values get saved in a mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, uuid

I save an `UUID` token in a `mysql` databse table. In next section of my `java` program, I need to do a query like this

```
String sql = "SELECT expiray_time FROM recover_password WHERE token = '"+token+"'";
```

this `token` is an `UUID` value generated before and it is saved in a `mysql` table.

But when I run my program I get an error saying `EmptyResultDataAccessException`. I think I get this error because the `UUID` token value is not in the same form which was there when generating and inserting in to the database. It is in a different form now.

I have saved UUID in my databse as a `text` type value.

My questions are

1. Is it correct to save `UUID` values in the type of `text` in the database?
2. How to compare the generated token value with the token value in the database?
3. Are `UUID` values get hashed or encrypted in to a different format when getting inserted into a database?
   Thank  you !

Answer (score 2):

1. If your UUID won't exceed 255 characters, then it's most preferable to use VARCHAR.
2. Use MySQL's STRCMP() function for string comparison.
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp

Comment: I am asking that Is it transformed in to a different form when getting saved in a database?

Comment: If you're inserting the UUID as it is, then it will be in plain text only. If you want to encrypt it, you can use built-in MySQL hash functions like SHA1(), MD5(), etc. A complete reference can be found here: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)

Comment: No, The issue is this is what I generated as some numbers and texts, But when I look at the database, it is completely different

Comment: Normally it saves as plain text only. Just check whether there's no encryption at your side. Can you just post the UUID value in your database.

Comment: I got it working. I have generated the UUID value by `UUID token = UUID.randomUUID();`, It worked after I added the following code snippet  `tring randomUUIDString = token.toString();` , then the `randomUUIDString` is passed as the token